# Give an example of a non-ellipsoid ovalid

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, surfaces

The compact, connected surfaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which the Gaussian curvature is always positive are called ovaloids.

So, ellipsoids are ovaloids.

Is there an ovaloid that is not an ellipsoid? Some literature?

Comment: If a compact surface $S$ has $K>0$, any small perturbation of $S$ will also have $K>0$. So yes, there are lots of ovaloids which is not ellipsoids.

Answer (score 0):

How about the surface with equation $x^4+y^4+z^4=1$?

Comment: so compactness is clear. what about gaussian curvature and connectedness